# Starlink vs 5G technology, are they directly competing services?

Tags: communication-satellite, technology, business

While the world is preparing for 5G mobile technology (which involves new devices for smartphones and stations), SpaceX is going to roll out its Starlink "constellation".

What I did not know is that they are going to provide a WiFi connection (I thought initially maybe they were planning 5G).

Source - screenshot of [WiFi via satellite](https://twitter.com/WilliamPicker/status/966807246079393792?s=09)?

Now if Starlink succeeds, will it be a service directly competitive to 5G as such?

Comment: This question is based upon a fake image. Basic questions like "maximum range of WiFi antennas" should be addressed elsewhere, e.g. ElectricalEngineering.SE

Comment: Starlink isn't a WiFi network. It can't be received on your phone or laptop. Starlink will require a large receiver which contains a set of phased array antennas. It's most similar current technology is dish based TV and internet; you'll need to mount the starlink receiver outside with a clear view of the sky. Once that's done it'll probably have an Ethernet jack that lets you hook it up to a router.

Comment: @Dragongeek Not even the Iridium requires large antennas, although it can get probably a better signal with it. I am sure that there will be StarLink-capable mobile phones, too, just like there are Iridium phones.

Comment: @peterh Phased array antennas are at the core of Starlink's technology and, currently, putting one in a phone is not really doable. Comparing iridium to starlink also really isn't fair ether as Starlink is designed to have multiple orders of magnitude more clients and internet speeds. Portable phone-sized iridium receivers are not fast enough to browse, they can barely do email and VoIP. Only the large, naval or plane versions approach speeds that are measures in Mbps.

Comment: @Dragongeek This is super-useful info, thank you.

Comment: @EverydayAstronaut "should be asked elsewhere" is not the same as "off topic here". If you search this site you'll find communications technology like WiFi in space is [discussed in many other well-received posts in the past](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=wifi) and so there is no basis for unilaterally stating that it is off-topic now. One does not vote to close as off-topic because one thinks it could be "better-asked elsewhere".

Comment: @uhoh true. This is not the only reason for my negative opinion, as mentioned in my first comment. Did I vote to close? Can't remember or check. Anyhow, the two of us have different opinions on when to cast downvotes or close votes (i.e. how to apply the rules), it's useless to argue about it every single time.

Comment: @EverydayAstronaut considering that both you and a moderator of the site took the time and effort to write good answers, probably the question is worth answering and keeping alive here. My comment is for the benefit of others considering close votes as well. Considering that the question and two answers are all well-received, I don't see the benefit to the site of closing the question as off-topic now. On the contrary, I think it's better to keep it active so future readers are more likely to see it and the answers.

Comment: @Dragongeek while cell phones don't have proper phased array antennas, they do have multiple antennas and I think in some cases the signals are combined. I don't know if the combination is done by phasing the two signals first, or if each has a preamp and ADC and then their data is combined digitally, but okay it's not a phased array antenna as we know it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This partial answer is not about the technical possibilities, but about Starlink's hypothetical relationship to 5G.

SpaceX's plans with Starlink are unclear at the moment. On the one hand, one should not expect it to be available in urban areas because it [will serve [the] least served](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/966298034978959361). This is obviously reasonable because big cities have the most advanced (and cheapest) infrastructure already. It could mean that Starlink will compete against terrestrial networks in areas where Internet access is more involved (i.e. slow and expensive). So, **Starlink will most likely not be an alternative to 5G in places where 5G is set up first.**

On the other hand, as was said [here](https://bitactro.com/starlink-internet/), it should help funding SpaceX's development of BFR. That seems somewhat contrary to serving the *least* served, because usually wealth correlates to some extend with population density (I guess). Elon Musk probably thinks of some compromise by mentioning "sparsely to moderately populated areas". So, **Starlink will probably compete with both wireless and wired ISPs in rural to suburban areas.**

[Rumors say](https://www.cbinsights.com/research/report/elon-musk-companies-disruption/) that Starlink might also be one further step to full [vertical integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_integration) of Tesla.

Read this article to know more [starlink vs 5g?](https://bitactro.com/starlink-vs-5g/)

Comment: I think it would be a nice option for the civil aviation, to provide online internet access on the passanger planes.

Comment: I honestly think that Musk said that Starlink is to serve ""sparsely to moderately populated areas", because he didn't want ISPs world wide to freak out. Starlink is going to have over 7000 satellites that cover just about every single inhabited place on this planet. The connections will be faster (latency, not necessarily bandwidth) than the fastest sea-cable. Starlink will most likely become the ISP of the world, all you would need is a pizza box sized antenna and you would have an internet connection with the lowest latency world wide.

Comment: It may be fair to note that Starlink is more than capable of handling high loads, and is projected too. Ontop of that LOS (line of sight) is more direct than ground-based telcos, so signal will be better regardless of location.

Answer (score 3):

WiFi from a satellite is actually impossible, due to a number of issues. Regulation wise WiFi only works because of the ability to have low power unlicensed devices, for it to work in space it would require a much more powerful system. The limit is [4 W EIRP](https://www.air802.com/fcc-rules-and-regulations.html). Furthermore, the movement of the satellite will create Doppler shift of the frequency, which will make the bandwidth too high to be supported.

What will actually be done I believe is that each device that wants to use Starlink will use some kind of a dedicated antenna. It might be like an ISP, using an antenna to send internet to a single house, or it might be something broader to send it to something like a Cruise ship, or even ISP to ISP links via satellite.

The frequency of Starlink will be above 10 GHz, well outside of the band of Wifi. At that high frequency, it is possible to have a hand-held device that could receive the satellite signals, as the antenna will be small.

Comment: Can you give any sources?

Comment: There's conflicting information about frequencies (initial application is Ku & Ka, nothing above 10Ghz, but there's discussion of activity above 25Ghz also). One firmly stated thing is that they will *not* talk to handhelds, instead requiring a pizzabox shaped user terminal to contain the phased array. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starlink_(satellite_constellation)#Internet_communication_satellite_characteristics

Comment: @Saiboogu yes there would be a finite number of transponder stations, on roofs or poles, then locally people can implement their own local access one way or the other: https://youtu.be/ZmEg95wPiVU?t=3000

Comment: I think the doppler shift could be compensated with the satellite electronics. And the $\approx$ 8km/s velocity of the satellites likely won't cause too much problem, it is only 0.000026c . An 5GHz wifi signal would get $\approx$ 100kHz deviation due to doppler, while a single Wifi channel is many megabit/sec wide. I see a more serious problem the creation of a directed signal on the mobil phone side. But I don't think that StarLink would use ordinary wifi.

Comment: It would be extremely difficult to compensate for a large barrage of wide weak signals over a limited bandwith. Starlink won't use Wi-fi, it just can't.

Comment: Radio amateurs use wifi over multiple kilometers with high gain antennas and noncompliant hardware. Surface-orbit wifi doesn't seem impossible to me.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.parabolicarc.com/2020/03/29/spacex-get-approval-for-1-million-starlink-ground-stations-in-usa/) appears to describe the Starlink ground station model. Not portable, but small, simple and presumably fairly cheap.

> Each ground station is just under 19 inches (.48 m) across.
>
> “It looks like a UFO on a stick,” SpaceX CEO Elon Musk said earlier this month. “It’s very important that you don’t need a specialist to install. The goal is for … just two instructions and they can be done in either order: Point at sky, plug in.”

That article doesn't explain what the downstream side of one of those base stations is, but I imagine it could be wired ethernet to a local network which might include WiFi base stations. It could also be one of the smaller scale 5G technologies. 5G includes a huge range of wavebands and protocols for different power levels, ranges and settings.